# Undead Dread Necromancer DR stacking?

Tags: dnd-3.5e

Quick question regarding damage reduction....

In the Book of Vile Darkness there is a template for Bone Creature which, theoretically would allow an animated-skeleton-style character (using human as base here).

Now, this template gives half damage from piercing and slashing weapons, but how does this stack with the DN ability "Lich Body" which gives DR x/Bludgeoning at certain levels?

Would a slashing/piercing attack take both half damage AND then another "x" amount knocked off from the Lich Body DR?

Now i know BoVD was a 3.0 book but i'm going on the "if there isn't a 3.5 version then you can use 3.0 ruling" way of thinking here so what do you reckon?

Answer (score 10):

From the 3.5 update booklet:

> Weapon Types: If a monster took half damage from certain weapon types, replace this with damage reduction 5/other weapon types. For example, skeletons took half damage from slashing and piercing weapons; now they have damage reduction 5/bludgeoning. Rarely use weapon types as a bypass for damage reduction.

The passage appears in the Monster Manual section, but the introduction clearly indicates that this is applicable to all monsters, even though specific changes are given for only some supplements.

So Bone Creatures change exactly like skeletons did, and now have DR 5/bludgeoning, which overlaps (does not stack) with the Lich Body DR and is adjudicated as normal.